# First Composer Package - autoloader not working

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I did my best to find a question/answer that applied, but I don't think I understand enough about the autoloader to recognize a suitable answer.

I have a package with the following composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "Pva_agent",
    "type":"library",
    "description" : "query the pva agent",
    "version":"0.1b",
    "authors" : [
        {
            "name":"Ed Greenberg",
            "email":"ed@precisionpros.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability":"dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Pva_agent": "."
        }
    }

}
```

My directory structure after composer installation of the package:

```
.
./vendor
./vendor/autoload.php
./vendor/Pva_agent
./vendor/Pva_agent/Agent.php
./vendor/Pva_agent/composer.json
./vendor/Pva_agent/.gitignore
./vendor/composer
./vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
./vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
./vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
./vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
./vendor/composer/installed.json
./vendor/composer/autoload_static.php
./vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php
./vendor/composer/LICENSE
./composer.lock
./composer.json
./test_pva_agent.php
```

My test program:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Pva_agent\Agent;

$agent = new Agent();
```

My result:

```
edg@arthur pva_project $ php test_pva_agent.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Pva_agent\Agent' not found in /home/edg/PhpstormProjects/pva_project/test_pva_agent.php on line 6
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/edg/PhpstormProjects/pva_project/test_pva_agent.php:0
edg@arthur pva_project $
```

I didn't think I needed the 'use' statement, since the autoloader should find the class, right?

Can somebody tell me where the problem lies?

Thanks,

Ed Greenberg

Answer (score 0):

Your **Pva_agent** library should not sit in the `vendor/` directory. This directory should contain only auto-generated data from Composer. This directory is usually not stored in VCS.

You should consider refactoring your directory structure to something similar to this one:

```
.
|____composer.json
|____composer.lock
|____src
| |____Pva_agent
|____vendor
```

Your library functionality should be added to `src/Pva_agent` directory.

Consider to use PSR-4 instead of PSR-0 for [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) functionality, as there is no need to regenerate the autoloader when you add classes. [dump-autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload) has to be run in case of PSR-0 after adding classed.

For the directory structure above and the PSR-4 autoloader your `composer.json` autoload section should look similar to this one:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Pva_agent\\": "src/Pva_agent" }
}
```

Your library should be auto loaded after this. Your auto-loaded library will be registered under the `Pva_agent` namespace.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks, Lukas, but your answer generates more questions :) composer put my library under vendor, just like it would put anyhthing that I got from the web.

Comment: Composer should not put your source code under the `vendor/`. When you dig into the `vendor/` folder you should see the path to your library in the list: `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`. You can check a structure of my [PhiKettle library](https://github.com/loftdigital/PhiKettle) as an example. Try to clone the project and run `composer update`.